# How to toggle closest children class

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

The issue I face is that I have identical "button-checkboxes", but once of of them is clicked, I only want the closest private class to change.

```
<span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" onclick="privateClick()" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o private"></i>
     <button>
     <input name="private" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
</span>
<span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" onclick="privateClick()" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o private"></i>
     <button>
     <input name="private" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
</span>
```

I currently use:

```
function privateClick()
{
    $(".private").toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');
}
```

to toggle the "checkbox button". But, obviously, if there is more then one button-checkbox, all of them toggle. So I have been trying with:

```
var closest_tag = $(this).find('.private').first();
closest_tag.toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');
```

Unfortunately, the class does not get toggled at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Attach privateClick() to your button's click event and change $(".private") to $(this)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The issue is that the .private class is inside the `<i>` tag and by doing that change, the classes within the <i> tag do not change :(

Comment: Why don't you post relevant part of your code? It's hard to tell what you have

Comment: I restructured the question to make it a little more clear of what I am trying to accomplish. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of your onclick event and just use jquery on event, like this:

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
var itag = $(this).find("i");
    itag.toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');
    itag.text(itag.attr("class"))
})
```

```css
button{
  display:block;
  padding:50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" id="1" data-color="white" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o private"></i>
        </button>
     <input name="private" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
</span>
<span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" id="1" data-color="white" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o private"></i>
        </button>
     <input name="private" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
</span/>
```

Comment: thanks! This seems to work for buttons were created at time of when the page was loaded. Now, I am trying to modify this script [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). The problem seems to be that any button that gets created after the page finished loading, for some reason it does not work with those

Comment: If you are adding buttons after the page load, then bind it to the document and use btn class to filter it. Like this $(document).on("click", ".btn", function(){ //your toggle code here });